# PHP LDAP, adding new entries into LDAP

Tags: php, directory, ldap, bind, ldap-query

I am wanting to create a form that I can fill out and once I submit it the form values can be pulled out and that person can be created into LDAP. I am not very experienced with LDAP infact I just worked towards making an LDAP bind work so I am needing some help. How can I add new users into LDAP through this form I can fill out? I know LDAP has an Add commands but I am not particularly sure on how to get started and what information needs to be passed for the person to be created in LDAP. If it helps, below is my code for LDAP bind.

```
<?php
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$x=1;
if($x==1)
{
    //LDAP stuff here.
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "mypass";


    $ds = ldap_connect('ldap://ldap:389');

        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    //Can't connect to LDAP.
    if( !ds )
    {
        echo "Error in contacting the LDAP server -- contact ";
        echo "technical services!  (Debug 1)";

        exit;
    }

    //Connection made -- bind anonymously and get dn for username.
    $bind = @ldap_bind($ds);

    //Check to make sure we're bound.
    if( !bind )
    {
        echo "Anonymous bind to LDAP FAILED.  Contact Tech Services! (Debug 2)";

        exit;
    }

    $search = ldap_search($ds, "ou=People,DC=sde,DC=goliat,DC=com", "uid=$username");

    //Make sure only ONE result was returned -- if not, they might've thrown a * into the username.  Bad user!
    if( ldap_count_entries($ds,$search) != 1 )
    {
        echo "Error processing username -- please try to login again. (Debug 3)";
        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);

    //Now, try to rebind with their full dn and password.
    $bind = @ldap_bind($ds, $info[0][dn], $password);
    if( !$bind || !isset($bind))
    {
        echo "Login failed -- please try again. (Debug 4)";
        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }

    //Now verify the previous search using their credentials.
    $search = ldap_search($ds, "ou=People,DC=sde,DC=goliat,DC=com", "cn=$name");

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
    if( $username == "myusername" )
    {

/*  
    very useful set of information to view the LDAP tree info from an array
    echo $username;
echo "<pre>".print_r($info[0],true)."</pre><br />";
*/
     echo $info[0][cn][0]; 
     echo ",";
     echo $info[0][mail][0];
     echo ",";
echo $info[0][telephonenumber][0];

        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error. Access Denied";
        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }
    ldap_close($ds);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a newUser.php (or whatever) file that checks to make sure that all of your required information is present, then send that info to the file you have started above.

Your `$bind` should take three variables...

`$bind = ldap_bind($ds, 'cn=root,dc=example,dc=com', secretPassword);`

For a pretty good guide to adding people to your LDAP server via PHP go to http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.ldap-add/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

An add request requires the distinguished name to be added and the attribute that are to be part of the entry, and optional request controls.

On another subject, your search has subtree scope and may return more than one entry that matches user name. There is no reason why there could not be multiple entries with the same RDN in different branches underneath the base object specified in the code - unless your directory server vendor has implemented an attribute uniqueness constraint.